# Quantum Principal Component analysis by Seth Lloyd

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I am currently reading the paper quantum principal component analysis from Seth Lloyd's article [Quantum Principal Component Analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0401) There is the following equation stated.

> Suppose that on is presented with *n* copies of $\rho$. A simple trick allows one to apply the unitary transformation $e^{-i\rho t}$ to any density matrix $\sigma$ up to $n$th order in $t$. Note that
> \begin{align}\label{eq1}\tag{1}
> \text{tr}_pe^{-iS\Delta t}\rho\otimes\sigma e^{iS\Delta t} &= \left(\cos^2\Delta t\right)\sigma + \left(\sin^2 \Delta t\right)\rho - i\sin\Delta t\left[\rho, \sigma\right] \\
> &= \sigma - i\Delta t\left[\rho, \sigma\right] + \mathcal O\left(\Delta t^2\right)
> \end{align}
> Here $\text{tr}_p$ is the partial trace over the first variable and $S$ is the swap operator. $S$ is a sparse matrix and so $e^{-iS\Delta t}$ can be performed efficiently [6-9]. Repeated application of \eqref{eq1}

I know from the qiskit website, that we can express $\mathrm{e}^{i\gamma B}$ as $\cos(\gamma)I + i\sin(\gamma)B $ with $\gamma$ being some real number and $B$ is an involutory matrix. Can someone explain me why there is only a single $\sigma$ and no $\rho$ in $(\cos^2\triangle t)\sigma$ and a single $\rho$ and no $\sigma$  in $(\sin^2\triangle t)\rho$? Is it because of the partial trace?

Any intuition or approach is welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, start by expanding $e^{-iS\Delta t}=\cos(\Delta t)I-i\sin(\Delta t)S$, so you'd be calculating
$$
(\cos(\Delta t)I-i\sin(\Delta t)S)\rho\otimes\sigma(\cos(\Delta t)I+i\sin(\Delta t)S).
$$
If you multiply out all the terms, then the $\cos^2(\Delta t)$ comes from the two $I$ terms, leaving you with $\rho\otimes\sigma$. If you trace out the first term, you're left with $\sigma$.

Similarly, $S(\rho\otimes\sigma)S=\sigma\otimes\rho$, so if you trace out the first system, you're left with $\rho$.

It's actually the cross-terms that are the trickier ones. Take, for example, $S(\rho\otimes\sigma)$. If I try to trace out the first system, I have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j,k}|j\rangle\langle k|\langle i,j|S\rho\otimes\sigma|i,k\rangle&=\sum_{i,j,k}|j\rangle\langle k|\langle j,i|\rho\otimes\sigma|i,k\rangle \\
&=\sum_{i,j,k}|j\rangle\langle k|\langle j|\rho|i\rangle\langle i|\sigma|k\rangle \\
&=\sum_{j,k}|j\rangle\langle k|\langle j|\rho\sigma|k\rangle \\
&=\rho\sigma.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful and insightful.